# How is the line integration defined in the most general setting?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, lebesgue-integral, line-integrals

A natural generalization of Riemann-Stieltjes integration is Lebesgue integration. Some would say that the use of Lebesgue integration would be overkill when treating differentiable or continuous functions, theoretically, Lebesgue integration describes things much simpler than RS-integration.

Likewise, is there a natural generalization of line integrals?

The standard definition of line integration is as follows:

> Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow L(\subset U)$ be a path in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Let $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function.
>
> Then, $\int_\gamma f$ is defined as $\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n \langle F(r(t_i)),\Delta r_i \rangle$ if it exsits.

I wonder if there exists a measure relates a path $\gamma$ to functions $f$, or other abstract definitions of line integrations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Line integrals are actually object from differential geometry, in the sense that they are linked to integration over (sub)manifolds. Hence it is not particularly interesting to integrate irregular functions on a smooth manifold. However, if you start with the formula $$\int_\gamma f\, ds = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\|\dot{\gamma(t)}\|\, dt$$, then you can try to understand when such an integral is defined.

Comment: @Siminore What is a definition of line integrals over manifolds?

Comment: It is a bit involved, you construct it by local coordinates (aka local charts) and by a partition of unity. Since differential geometers like smooth objects, integration theory for irregular functions on smooth manifolds is seldom seen in books.